# The overlapping of two buttons

Tags: android

Android 2 buttons are defined in xml

AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams

Using the two buttons was placed overlapping each other.

param1 = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 10, 20);

param2 = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 10, 30);

btn1.setLayoutParams (param1);
btn2.setLayoutParams (param2);

These buttons are overlapping each other.

Located under the button (btn1) and Back button Back to report abuse if it is in xml.

Btn1 dynamically from java code, but I want to raise up

What is hidden in the overlapping state btn2 to be able to climb up btn1?

Answer (score 1):

You can use View.bringChildToFront(btn2) where View is the container of the buttons. This brings btn2 to be at the front.